# REST API : Get post title with comment

Tags: comments, rest-api

I'm having trouble registering a rest field with the post title when doing a "GET /wp/v2/comments". I'd like to be able to have field "title" with the raw (or rendered?) real post title.

My goal is to list a user's comments and easily get the parent post title in a single GET request without having to check the post id.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hello Anthony - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Please take a moment to review the "[ask]" page in our [help], then file an [edit] to include any additional details such as the code from your most recent attempt at solving the issue.  It would also be useful if you could explicitly phrase your specific question in the form of a question somewhere in there :)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `registering a rest field with the post title,` and doubly so with the appended `when doing a "GET /wp/v2/comments"`. `register_rest_field()` does not take in any post-specific information, and REST fields are registered to object types, not per-endpoint.